# ng-repeat not iterating through list of images in JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm quite new to Angular and am having trouble using the $http service to make a GET request for images in JSON (just a plain array of images). For every image, I want to repeat that and add them into my ng-src. I'm trying to achieve a layout similar to  Instagram.

So I think the $http.get part is correct where I store it into $scope.imageUrls, and from there I iterate through it using ng-repeat. Then from there, for each iteration, I plug that into ng-src in my img tag and I just don't know how to debug from there.

HTML:

```
<div class="posts" ng-controller="PostController">
  <div class="post" ng-repeat="imageUrl in imageUrls">
    <img class="photo" ng-src="{{imageUrl}}" />
    <div class="post-box">
      <div><span class="likes"> # </span> Likes</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('instagram', []);

app.controller('PostController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

  $http.get('https://codesmith-precourse.firebaseio.com/instagram/-JqL35o8u6t3dTQaFXSV.json')
    .then(function (data) {
      $scope.imageUrls = data;

      console.log($scope.imageUrls);
    });
}]);
```

I tried used console.log to check for errors, but the data seems to be there. Is it just returning the block of data rather than each element/image in the JSON?

Checking the console: [console.log($scope.imageUrls)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dot3I.png)

I also tried using {{imageUrl.url}} as ng-src but that seemed to trigger errors as well. I set up a Plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/yQpCIRp9FHdDHTMA1HCL?p=preview

This has been bugging me for awhile, so if you can help, thanks!

Comment: Try changing your assignment to `$scope.imageUrls = data.data`. As you can see in the output from `console.log`, your array of images is in `data` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I update your plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/hNn1YdVh8w7l3dEgh3LU?p=preview:

In $http you get a responsa that contains more informations that only data. To get data you must do it :

```
$http.get('https://codesmith-precourse.firebaseio.com/instagram/-JqL35o8u6t3dTQaFXSV.json')
    .then(function (response) {
      $scope.imageUrls = response.data;

      console.log($scope.imageUrls); 
    });
```

And in ng-repeat you must add track by argument because image can be duplicate

Answer (score 2):

You are setting imageUrls to an object. It needs to be an array. If you look in the debugger your response is this:

[image]

You want whats in `data.data` (You also should define the `imageUrls` variable (`$scope.imageUrls = []')`

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="instagram">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Angular</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="posts" ng-controller="PostController">
    <div class="post" ng-repeat="imageUrl in imageUrls">
      <img class="photo" ng-src="{{imageUrl}}" />
      <div class="post-box">
        <div><span class="likes"> # </span> Likes</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('instagram', []);

    app.controller('PostController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.imageUrls = [];
      $http.get('https://codesmith-precourse.firebaseio.com/instagram/-JqL35o8u6t3dTQaFXSV.json')
        .then(function (data) {
              $scope.imageUrls = data.data;

        });
    }]);


  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no need to iterate over an array just to copy the values. We can simply assign `imageUrls = data.data;`

Comment: You are correct. That iteration isn't needed. It's already an array

Answer (score 0):

updated plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/agVrWD8I4581a0702ehy?p=preview

you have to get `data.data`

```
 $http.get('https://codesmith-precourse.firebaseio.com/instagram/-JqL35o8u6t3dTQaFXSV.json')
        .then(function (data) {
          $scope.imageUrls = data.data;

        });
```

and use `track by $index` in the ng-repeat because you have duplicate

```
  <div class="posts" ng-controller="PostController">
    <div class="post" ng-repeat="imageUrl in imageUrls track by $index">
      <img class="photo" ng-src="{{imageUrl}}" />
      <div class="post-box">
        <div><span class="likes"> # </span> Likes</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: we just write the answer in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in $http method the response value is an object containing "data" element that is the data you need so use this :
`$scope.imageUrls = data.data;`
then you have duplicate image url , in this case ng-repeat returns an error so use this instead :
`<div class="post" ng-repeat="imageUrl in imageUrls track by $index">`

Comment: How does it differ from Silvinus answer?

Comment: @fracz you r correct, but when i was typing my answer nobody answered this question.